# Shading multiple areas between vertical lines in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, shading, fillbetween

I'm working with `pgfplots` on shading areas between vertical lines. So basically to create rectangles, restricted by 2 values on the x-axis.

This can be done by drawing using `tikz`, but I would like to create multiple shapes like that. So for example, I have 100 values on the x-axis and want to pair them in order to shade the area between value 1 and 2; 3 and 4; and so on.

I thought about separating all x-values with even/uneven indeces and then filling the area in between, if I define them as functions like `x=(x-value)`.

I know, this question is more of a riddle than a direct `pgfplots`-question, but probably I just didn't realize that there indeed is a very simple solution.

**MWE:**
Here, I would like to shade everything between 2 and 4 and between 5 and 6

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        %ymin = -3, ymax = 3,
        ]
        \addplot[black,only marks]
        table[x=A,y=B] {
            A   B
            2   0
            4   0
            5   0
            6   0
                };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Edit:
Possible solution using Excel I came up with:

```
\fill [green,opacity=0.9] (axis cs:2,0) rectangle (axis cs:4,10);
```

This creates shaded areas. I inserted my lists of x-values and let excel create a list with the x-values inserted. Then back to pgfplot and it works.
But probably there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Hi Morbo, welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a small, complete LaTeX document (a.k.a. [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/110998)) that illustrates your questions/problems. For anyone trying to help you, it should be possible to cut and paste the code and experiment with it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a loop, with e.g. `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} % with compat=1.11 or higher axis cs is the default coordinate system, so you don't have to state that explicitly in the \fill below
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        %ymin = -3, ymax = 3,
        ]
        \addplot[black,only marks]
        table[x=A,y=B] {
            A   B
            2   0
            4   1
            5   0
            20   1
                };

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,4,...,20}{
   \fill [blue!10]
       (#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
         rectangle 
       (#1+1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How could you use this command to shade the areas between 2-4 and 5-20 only?

Comment: @Morbo No point in using a loop for that, just use `\fill` twice with the appropriate x-coordinates/

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info!
I probably didn't explain my goal not sufficiently, but filling only between the observed values would be what I'm looking for. The challenge is doing that for more than 100 values.